# Update this method so that its implementation is not identical to getAliases Sonar issue

Tags: coding-standards, magento-coding-standard

I am working with magento `patches` but when try to validate it with sonar it's failed due to same function body in below function.

```
/**
 * Get Aliases
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getAliases()
{
    return [];
}

/**
 * Get Dependencies
 *
 * @return array
 */
public static function getDependencies()
{
    return [];
}
```

We can bypass sonar warning/error by writing `//NOSONAR` for one line is there any other ignore method where we can ignore block of code from sonar.